# Search result theming

Tags: search

I have problems configuring the search-result.tpl. Is it so, that the fields set in Search result view mode are always snippet'ized as plain text? I have for example a taxonomy term on each node, which I set to appear as link in the Search result view mode, yet it is always output as plain text.

I'm using Custom Search and Search API, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 7 here, which thankfully has more options for you that Drupal 6.

I don't recall the last time I fully traced this out (and it's complicated), but [search_excerpt](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_excerpt/7) does call [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) and [check_plain](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7).

You can take a look at [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search-result.tpl.php/7), [template_preprocess_search_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7), [hook_node_search_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_search_result/7) to see what your options are.

Personally, I would build up my own entries in `$variables` in the preprocess, and display them in the template.  One option is to make a custom node view for the search results, uild it up with the UI, and then use this,something like:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_search_result (&$variables)
{
  $result = $variables['result'];
  $node = $result['node']; // not 100% positive that this is the right place in D7
  $variables['my_custom_search_result_view'] = node_view($node,
    'my_custom_search_result_view');
}
```

and then use `$my_custom_search_result_view` in search-result.tpl.php.

Not a full solution for you, but it should be a decent start.

Comment: Well, thanks MPD for your explanation, but this is actualy a piece that I understand :) What I don't get is - what is the use of Search Result view mode if the fields are not formatted as set in Manage Display. I disabled search-result(s).tpl files for a moment and cleared cache, thinking that they might override the view mode, but this is apparently not the case...

Comment: @Artur, I probably wasn't clear.  I am suggesting *not* using $snippet at all in the template.  Rather, make your own view mode, and use that in your search result template.

Comment: Ah so! My brain stays behind sometimes. Yep, that worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn much more about this issue here
https://www.drupal.org/node/1166114